# parse data using regex and converting it into tuple

Tags: python, regex

I need to find a city with the highest population using regex, data is presented in such way:

```
data = ["id,name,poppulation,is_capital",
"3024,eu_kyiv,24834,y",
"3025,eu_volynia,20231,n",
"3026,eu_galych,23745,n",
"4892,me_medina,18038,n",
"4401,af_cairo,18946,y",
"4700,me_tabriz,13421,n",
"4899,me_bagdad,22723,y",
"6600,af_zulu,09720,n"]
```

I've done this so far:

```
def max_population(data):
    lst = []
    for items in data:
        a = re.findall(r',\S+_\S+,[0-9]+', items)
        lst += [[b for b in i.split(',') if b] for i in a]
    return max(lst, key=lambda x:int(x[1]))
```

But function should return (str, int) tuple, is it possible to change my code in a way that it will return tuple without iterating list once again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following long line get the wanted result `(str, int) tuple`:

```
def max_population(data):
    p=max([(re.findall(r"(\w*),\d*,\w$",i)[0],int(re.findall(r"(\d*),\w$",i)[0])) for n,i in enumerate(data) if n>0],key=lambda x:int(x[1]) )
    return p
```

in this line,`enumerate(data)` and `n>0` were used to skip the header `"id,name,poppulation,is_capital"`. But if `data` has no-header the, line would be:

```
def max_population(data):
    p=max([(re.findall(r"(\w*),\d*,\w$",i)[0],int(re.findall(r"(\d*),\w$",i)[0])) for i in data],key=lambda x:int(x[1]) )
    return p
```

The result for both is `('eu_kyiv', 24834)`

Answer (score 1):

All your strings are separated by a comma. You could get the max value using split and check if the third value is a digit and is greater than the first value of the tuple.

If it is, set it as the new highest value.

```
def max_population(data):
    result = None
    for s in data:
        parts = s.split(",")
        if not parts[2].isdigit():
            continue
        tup = (parts[1], int(parts[2]))
        if result is None or tup[1] > result[1]:
            result = tup

    return result


print(max_population(items))
```

Output

```
('eu_kyiv', 24834)
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/fGIXzN)

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of tuples instead of a list of lists.

```
import re

data = ["id,name,poppulation,is_capital",
"3024,eu_kyiv,24834,y",
"3025,eu_volynia,20231,n",
"3026,eu_galych,23745,n",
"4892,me_medina,18038,n",
"4401,af_cairo,18946,y",
"4700,me_tabriz,13421,n",
"4899,me_bagdad,22723,y",
"6600,af_zulu,09720,n"]

def max_population(data):
    lst = []
    for items in data:
        a = re.findall(r',\S+_\S+,[0-9]+', items)
        lst += [tuple(b for b in i.split(',') if b) for i in a]
    return max(lst, key=lambda x:int(x[1]))

print(max_population(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a mapping function to map the types to the data and use the `operator.itemgetter` function as your key in `max`:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

def f(row):
   # Use a tuple of types to cast str to the desired type
   types = (str, int)
   # slice here to get the city and population values
   return tuple(t(val) for t, val in zip(types, row.split(',')[1:3]))


# Have max consume a map on the data excluding the
# header row (hence the slice)
max(map(f, data[1:]), key=itemgetter(1))
('eu_kyiv', 24834)
```